# How can I find the edition of Oracle installed?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, licensing

I have inherited an installation of Oracle 11G on CentOS. I know the version by running:

`SELECT * FROM v$version;`

Result: `Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production`

However, I am trying to find the edition of Oracle installed for licensing purposes. Everyone keeps telling me it is a 'Lite' version...
[The Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/license.111/b28287/editions.htm) tells me there are 5 editions:

From everything I have read when googling this, people say that if the results from `select * from v$version` does not say **Enterprise**, then it is **Standard**. I do not believe that I can go by that as there are 5 editions and two of them are separate types of Standard Edition. I need to know the exact edition installed.

Does anyone have any idea who I can determine what exact edition is installed?

Thanks!

Comment: "Standard Edition" and "Standard Edition One" are licensing terms only.  There is absolutely no difference between the bits that are installed.  It's just a question of whether your license supports the deployment of those bits on that particular server with the particular features enabled.  The "Personal Edition" is just the enterprise edition licensed for a single user on a local machine.  I believe personal would report as enterprise but I haven't looked in a long time.  It appears that you have installed the standard edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running this on 11g Enterprise

> select * from v$version where banner like 'Oracle%';

shows

```
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.1.0.7.0 - 64bit Production
```

If it doesn't say Enterprise or XE then it is Standard

Answer (score 0):

Mine tells me it's Enterprise

```
SQL> select  * from v$version;

Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0 - 64bi
PL/SQL Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production
CORE    10.2.0.1.0  Production
TNS for IBM/AIX RISC System/6000: Version 10.2.0.1.0 - Productio
NLSRTL Version 10.2.0.1.0 - Production
```